# Is there a way to highlight my tree path in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to highlight the tree path in the file I'm currently editing like Git does when I have uncommitted changes in a file? When I'm editing a file it only highlights the file, like this: [Only file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PowYS.png), I would like to highlight like this: [Git example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fxBH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi are you asking about this highlight ? I'm not sure either how to change the settings in VSCode but im currently using the Dark+ (default dark) theme in VSCode, i guess you can try change the theme in VSCode, hope it works ![]
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSBmV.png)

Comment: It's because your Git has uncommitted changes, then it highlights the path tree, like the image I posted "Git example"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).